# Converting multiple subdomains (both http and https) to www.domain.com using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I've got a dozen old subdomains that have been indexed by Google.  Not only have parts of my site been indexed, but they have been indexed as both http AND https.

I've managed to redirect all the subdomains properly, provided they are not https, but can't get any of the https subdomains to property redirect.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain3.mysite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great until someone goes to: https://subdomain2.mysite.com$ which is not redirected back to http://www.mysite.com$

How can I get this to work?  Additionally, I'm guessing there is an easier way to make it happen than setting up a dozen pairs of Rewrite conditions/rewrite rule? Is there any way to do this in just a few lines, including one where I list all the subdomains?

Any suggestions would be great, and yes, I've gone through a few dozen threads here looking for the answer and have tested various tips offered, though none of the questions I saw pertained to this exact situation.

Thank you!

Comment: Why wouldn't `https://subdomain2.mysite.com` be redirected to `http://www.mysite.com`? Do SSL requests end up in a different document root? Are these rules only in the non-SSL vhost?

Comment: @JonLin I'm not sure why it isn't working, which is why I'm posting here.  SSL requests aren't resulting in any form of redirect at all.

Comment: Any other feedback?  I was very excited to get some help from the StackOverFlow community . . . thanks!

Comment: Your rules work fine when I put them in a blank htaccess file in a brand new install of apache 2.2. Aside from going through all of your logs, I don't know why you're having issues. There's nothing wrong with your rules.

Comment: @JonLin I know that they work, but they aren't working for redirecting from https to http for the above listed subdomains. They only work for http to http.

Comment: Then you should look at your SSL vhost, not the rules themselves. If the SSL requests aren't running the rules? Why? A million possible reasons, you have to look into that. And from my first comment **"Do SSL requests end up in a different document root? Are these rules only in the non-SSL vhost?**" should be a great place to start your investigation.